# Show/Hide Select Option Based on the Type of User

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show/hide option from a select drop-down for free user & paid user form a php session value.

```
   <select id="book" name="book" style="display:none" onchange="update_session_value(this.value)">
        <option id = "c1" class="b1" value="A1">A1</option> 
        <option id = "c2" class="b1" value="A2">A2</option> 
        <option id = "c3" class="b2" value="A3">A3</option> 
        <option id = "c4"class="b2" value="A4">A4</option> 
    </select>
```

If

```
$_SESSION['mytype']= freeuser;
```

then hide option c1 & c2 & show c3 & c4 
if

```
$_SESSION['mytype']= paiduser;
```

then hide c3, c4 & show c1, c2

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you need some JavaScript with `if/then` logic. Have you researched any of that?

Comment: What you've done here is given us a set of requirements. We're not a code writing service. We expect that you'll do research and make an attempt before posting. What have you tried? What specific question do you have besides "How do I get my requirements coded?

Comment: You used a few tags that don't appear to be relevant. One (tag) that should be there though, would be the "session" tag.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner `css` also not relevant in this particular issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Sorry about the issue. I needed some ideas. I don't think you are in code writing service, i think you (who are here) are expert and i'm also trying to be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
   <select id="book" name="book" style="display:none" onchange="update_session_value(this.value)">
<?php if ($_SESSION['mytype'] === 'paiduser') { ?>
        <option id = "c1" class="b1" value="A1">A1</option> 
        <option id = "c2" class="b1" value="A2">A2</option> 
<?php } else { ?>
        <option id = "c3" class="b2" value="A3">A3</option> 
        <option id = "c4"class="b2" value="A4">A4</option> 
<?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: We tend not to answer poor questions that don't belong here in the first place as it just encourages more poor questions. Even if the question were appropriate for Stack Overflow, your answer isn't as it doesn't explain anything about the code you've provided.